# mount + how to identify if local folder is mounted as read only

Tags: linux, mount

In my Linux box – red-hat version – 6.7

**/dev/mapper/HOME-export**    is mounted to **/export**
As the following:

```
 df  /export
 Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/HOME-export   35G   27G  7.9G  78% /export
```

How I can identify if **/export**  is mounted as read only?

second question:

how to mount /export only as read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `mount` without args.
`mount |grep export`

Comment: hi - second - how to mount /export only as read only * what is the syntax ) ?

Comment: `mount -o ro <other params>`

Answer (score 1):

`mount -l` (actually implied by just `mount`) will list all of the filesystems mounted in the current namespace (each process can have its own mount namespace or inherit it from its parent. This is useful for containers).

`mount -l` is currently implemented by reading `/proc/self/mountinfo`. Top-level fields are separated by spaces. Field 5 is the mount location, and field 6 has either `rw` or `ro` as the first comma-separated subfield (Note that after field 6 is a number of optional fields, before the `-`).

For more information, see `proc(5)`